# BigQuery: SELECT in WHERE-clause with filter based on a value in the current row

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I know the title is probably pretty stupid but I have a hard time phrasing it differently.

I have to use BigQuery at work atm for some report. BigQuery is connected to a Google Analytics view of ours. This gives us a dataset with 1 table for each day. The rows of the tables are user-sessions on our site, while columns have some information about the sessions.

The problem I have is the following: 
I want to select sessions with transactions, but only if the user was referred to our site by a certain referrer in the last x days before the transaction happened. I'm only familiar with basic SQL and not with any advanced concepts. It's really frustrating to me because this would be a no-brainer with any proper programming language given a .csv of the data, but I'm lacking knowledge of the relevant concepts in SQL.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `dataset.ga_sessions_2017*`
WHERE 
  totals.transactions > 0 AND
  fullVisitorId IN (SELECT
                        fullVisitorId 
                    FROM 
                        `dataset.ga_sessions_2017*` 
                    WHERE 
                         trafficSource.source = "xyz.com"
                    ) AND
  < date difference thing>
```

I could filter for the date difference like I did with the trafficSource (referrer). The problem for me is that while "xyz.com" is a static thing, I'd need to reference the date value of the current row I'm in. So the date by which I'd filter the 2nd SELECT would be dynamically changing from row to row. Can anyone guide me on how this is usually done? This seems like a thing that would come up often.

Comment: Well it's hard to say this, but you better can some bigquery mentoring, as this is too complex and multiple concepts needs to be understood for you.

Comment: There are also a lot of cases not covered here - within 6 days a lot of transactions and referrals can happen. Is your use case more of a funnel with clear start and end, or only a clear end and conditional time frame?
What happens is someone has multiple transactions and referrals within 6 days?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the GA tables specifically, but having written some [wildcard queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables) in BigQuery before, I think what you're looking for can be done using the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` pseudo column:

```
CAST(_TABLE_SUFFIX AS INT64) >= 1217
```

Where `1217` is today's date in MMDD format minus 3 days, assuming the table names are _20171217, _20171218, etc. Otherwise you can just use `REPLACE` to remove underscores before casting to an int. There are also functions that will generate today's date for you if you needed this query to run automatically.

Also, I think the `fullVisitorId` business could be replaced with a simple `WHERE trafficSource.source = "xyz.com"` but it's hard to say for sure without being able to run the query myself.

So the full query would look something like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `dataset.ga_sessions_2017*`
WHERE 
  totals.transactions > 0 AND
  trafficSource.source = "xyz.com" AND
  CAST(_TABLE_SUFFIX AS INT64) >= 1217
```